# Azure data factory AD access token using certificate

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-data-factory

How to get access token from AAD authentication service using certificate in Azure data factory web activity , I can not use client secret for this , Certificate from Service principle is already stored in Azure key vault

My ADF pipeline flow is like thuis

1)Web activity to point to the certificate stored in keyvalut
2)web activity url as https://login.microsoftonline.com//oath2/token
and in body
@concat('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=',,'&client_assertion=',activity('Web1').output.cer,'&client_assertion_type=','urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer','&resource=','https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api')

Getting error as

Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - 'NotFound', message - 'The requested resource does not exist on the server. Please verify the request server and retry'

Comment: May I know which API do you want to call with the access token?

Comment: Use case is to trigger powerBI dashboard refresh  from  ADF , I am using below link "https://www.moderndata.ai/2019/05/powerbi-dataset-refresh-using-adf/"

Comment: But as per my company policy i have to use certificate in SPN instead of client secret

Comment: Try to use [`Client certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#client-certificate) in the web activity to call the powerbi rest api directly.

Comment: with direct call t powerBI with certificate authentication getting forbidden errror

Comment: for generating token i am using the expression as below in the webactivity body

Comment: @concat('grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=',<client id>,'&client_assertion=',activity('Web1').output,'&client_assertion_type=','urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer','&resource=','https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api')

Comment: here for client assertion i have a web activity which get certificate from keyvalut . i am using activity('Web1').output.cer as the client_assertion value? getting 401 error on resource not found on server

Comment: added this detail in the question